# Dealin with different Python versions using Pip (Mac OS X 10.9.5)

Tags: python, macos, pip

I'm dealin with installation problems for python 3.4 using Pip.
I have python versions 3.4(.3) and 2.5, 2.7
When i pip install a package, it will only be available on 2.7 
I found a 'solution' on : 
[pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions/33917887?noredirect=1#comment55598509_33917887)

But seems not to work, maybe outdated..

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your Q, but [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) are the way to go. I really like [Anaconda's envs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html) for keeping Python versions and various packages straight.

Comment: The thing is. I used Anaconda till 1 week ago, it doesn't support boto3 and i need to use that package.. install python package is a mess

Comment: What do you mean by support? I use boto3 inside an Anaconda env. You can still use `pip` inside of the env (best to use only when there's no `conda` package). Just make sure you `source activate` the right env before installing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, since it sounds like you have Anaconda and had trouble installing boto3, here's my workflow:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4 anaconda
```

Leave out `anaconda` if you want a completely clean Python-only environment. Substitute `myenv` for whatever name you like. Now activate:

```
source activate myenv
```

...and install `boto3`:

```
pip install boto3
```

That works for me.

Comment: Thank you !! This worked for me. I installed the packages in the env and it worked !